# Why use an un-squared L2-norm regularizer?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

Presumably it would be useful if you want to penalize small values more and large values less, but L1-norm shouldn't work too bad in those cases either and you get the benefit of sparsity. The only advantage I can think of is rotational invariance, but why don't take the square and make life easier?

Comment: Why use it in which situation? Some mathematicians use things just to study them. It sounds like you have an application in mind though.

Comment: In machine learning problems where one adds a regularizer to a loss function in empirical risk minimization.